# MySQL complex ranking query

Tags: mysql

I need to rank users in MySQL where the rank takes into account both ties and continues to counts the tied users as part of the rank.. For example..

```
points    rank 
 100        1
 100        1
 100        1
 70         4
 70         4
 60         5
 50         6
 40         7
 40         7
 10         8
 0          9
 0          9
```

Using the code below I'm ranking as follows...

```
points    rank    game 
 100        1       1
 100        1       1
 100        1       1
 70         2       1
 70         2       1
 60         3       1
 50         4       1
 40         5       1
 40         5       1
 10         6       1
 0          7       1
 0          7       1

UPDATE rank_table
JOIN   (SELECT f.points ,
IF     (@lastPoint <> f.points,
   @curRank := @curRank +1, 
   @curRank) AS rank, 
   @lastPoint := f.points
FROM   rank_table f
JOIN   (SELECT @curRank := 0, @lastPoint := -1) r
WHERE f.game =1
ORDER BY f.points DESC
) ranks ON (ranks.points = rank_table.points)
SET rank_table.rank = ranks.rank WHERE rank_table.game =1;
```

Would anyone know it this is possible..?

Comment: it is possible, you just need to add one more variable to track the rank state.

Comment: Like newtover said, you need another variable such as $realRank that you will always increment when processing a row. You will use the realRank when $lastPoint <> f.points is true.

Comment: Your new rank is the number of players having more points than you. You do not need any mysql-variable.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need any mysql-variable.

Your new rank is the number of players having more points than you.

```
update 
    result 
join (
    select 
        n.id, count(distinct q.id) total 
    from result n 
    left join result q 
    on 
        q.points > n.points
    group by n.id) m
on     
    m.id = id
set rank=m.total + 1
```

(assuming there is some kind of `id` like `player_id`)

Comment: Thanks, didn't think you could do this without variables. When I run the above though I get the following error _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1052, "Column 'id' in on clause is ambiguous")

Comment: do you have any kind of primary key in your rank_table?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the delay in getting back to you. I fixed the problem I described above, and the query ALMOST seems to work. It just never seems to start from a rank of 1, see this fiddle  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b36b/1. It seems much quicker so thanks for suggesting this, hope I can get it working for rank of 1. Any suggestions welcome :)

Comment: take off the +1 in the end, and everything will work as expected :)

Comment: Already tried that, result in two ranks of 1 for the top two distinctive points...  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81361/1 ..?

Comment: My fault, updated the count(*) to count(distinct n.id) and added +1 again. It should work now :) sorry